# Increasing heap size for JRuby using jruby_opts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, passenger, jruby, jrubyonrails

I am having issues with increasing the heap size for JRuby. The application is running Phusion Passenger and I installed JRuby using RVM.

I have tried

```
export JRUBY_OPTS="-J-Xmx1024m"
```

But it doesn't change the heap size. I tried

```
jruby -J-Xmx1024m
```

but it doesn't return and gets stuck.

I am not sure at this point how increase the limit. I am getting

> gc overhead limit exceeded

quite frequently which stops the application. And the web application is super slow.

Also how to know if the `Xmx` is set. I am doing `ps aux | grep jruby` and getting below in return:

```
apache   11646 74.1 33.4 1861684 687864 ?      Sl   14:00  29:24 /usr/bin/java -Djdk.home= -Djruby.home=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.16 -Djruby.script=jruby -Djruby.shell=/bin/sh -Djffi.boot.library.path=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.16/lib/jni:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.16/lib/jni/x86_64-Linux:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.16/lib/jni/i386-Linux:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.16/lib/jni/arm-Linux **-Xmx500m -Xss2048k** -Dsun.java.command=org.jruby.Main -cp  -Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.16/lib/jruby.jar org/jruby/Main /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/passenger-4.0.41/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb
```

Above command shows that jruby is using default `Xmx` options.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Passenger under Apache, you should use SetEnv in your vhost to set the environment variables to use with the process. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html

```
SetEnv JRUBY_OPTS -J-Xmx1024m
```